# Can I shorten this noun phrase using compounds?

Tags: grammaticality, compounds

So I have this sentence in mind:

> The current of the field coil of the motor is ...

Is it correct use compounds to write this sentence in a shorter way, like this (my attempt):

> The motor field coil current is ...

I am not sure of this sentence because I doubt that the reader will understand that the field coil *is* that of the motor.

Comment: Please [edit] this to add the research you did when you tried to answer this question yourself before asking it here.

Comment: My question *is* about whether my shortened sentence is correct.

Comment: Yes, and once you've shown that you have tried to figure that out already, then your question will be allowed. If you don't then it is off-topic. Proof reading questions are forbidden.

Comment: So I'm supposed to edit the post saying this:

Edit: My attempt is : [insert sentence]?

Comment: For this question to be acceptable you would have to have asked two native speakers of English who gave you different answers. If your off-site proof readers disagree, then we will be happy to help.

Comment: OK, this was my attempt. I am not a native English speaker and I didn't ask any native English speaker. So I just remove my attempt, and leave the sentence that I want to be shortened?

Comment: @DigiNinGravy: If you give a sentence and a particular way to shorten a specific aspect and you can elaborate why you are uncertain whether this is correct – then this would be a good question for this site.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Fine.

Comment: _The current of the field coil of the motor is ...._ isn't a sentence, shortened or not. So you can't tell if it's grammatical in context. It's a noun phrase, and it's precise (though probably _in_ would be better before _the field coil_, since _current_ is a metaphorical liquid, requiring containers for flow). The noun phrase compound _the motor field coil current_ **could** mean the same thing, but it could also mean something else, since noun compounds lose information when they shed their prepositions. Consider the difference between _snake bite_ and _pony ride_, for instance.

Comment: The current that flows through the field coil of the motor is....

Comment: Pushing this to the reopen queue since a specific source of concern in the text was clearly identified. This is not proofreading (anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form compounds like that in English, but it’s not a very good idea since they are difficult to understand, if not ambiguous.

Let’s first take a look at **written language**. Without any hyphens, it implies the following structure:

> The {motor [field (coil current)]} is …

This does not make sense: *Field* does not specify *coil current* but *field coil* specifies *current.* English orthography uses hyphens to clarify this distinction, so you would have to write *field-coil current.*

With *motor,* we have the same problem: Does *motor* specify *field-coil current* or does *motor field coil* specify *current?* Your original sentence suggests the latter, but if I understand everything correctly, the first version makes (the same) sense as well; so we can but do not have to add another hyphen here. I would consider adding this hyphen a bad idea, since *motor-field-coil current* could also be read as:

> {[(motor field) coil] current}

i.e., *motor field* specifies *coil,* which does not make sense.

Thus we arrive at:

> The motor field-coil current is …

This can be read, but with difficulties.

In **spoken language**, you do not have hyphens but have to convey the structure of this compound by intonation and pauses. While possible, this is difficult to perform and difficult to understand.

Note that in **both cases**, you lose the specific relation between the components of the compound (as noted by [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361808/can-i-shorten-this-noun-phrase-using-compounds/361871#comment842058_361808)). Often but not always, this can be deduced from context. For example, the reader could be confused about, whether the field coil is a part of the motor or just happens to be located next to the motor. Moreover even if the discarded information is not necessary, it may still help – redundancy aids intelligibility.

---

Due to all of the above, nested compounds usually aren’t such a good idea in the English language¹. You can avoid them by replacing at least one composition by a possessive or *of* construct, for example:

> The motor’s field-coil current is …
>   The field-coil current of the motor is …
>   The current of the motor’s field coil is …

<sup>¹ Other languages like German are notorious for using them.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Just write it the standard way you would find it in a textbook:

> The field coil current of the motor depends on ...

or

> The motor’s field coil current depends on ...